# Возможно ли объявить структуру внутри макроса?

Tags: c, макрос, метапрограммирование

Возможно ли объявить структуру внутри макроса ?
Вот пример, компилятор ругается, что я делаю не парвильно?

```
#define EXEMPLE (type, arg) \
            struct TEST {   \
                type #arg;  \
            }

EXEMPLE(int, asd);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Убери решётку перед arg. Добавление решетки делает параметр константой строки.

Comment: так же ругается

Comment: Еще пробел перед скобкой убери... `#define EXEMPLE(` https://godbolt.org/z/of4a5bs6v

Comment: @ori, благодарю

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Уберите решетку.
2. Не наводите красоту - уберите пробел между именем макроса и скобкой.
3. Убедитесь, что все [работает](https://ideone.com/UVHDZM).

Вот код:

```
#define EXEMPLE(type, arg) \
            struct TEST {  \
                type arg;  \
            }
```